# How to get parent tag attributes of lxml.etree like 'KEY', 'NAME', Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lxml

I want to find Parent for the XML Tag, How to fetch Tag Attributes.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

Request_URL = 'http://dataportal.ins.tn/WebApi/GetDimensionElements'
Method_Post_Body = "<QueryMessage lcid='1033'> <DataWhere> <DimensionId>OBJ5258839</DimensionId> </DataWhere> </QueryMessage>"
Post_Response = requests.post(Request_URL, data=Method_Post_Body, headers={'Content-type': 'text/xml'})

XRoot = etree.fromstring(Post_Response.content)
for Tag_1 in XRoot[1]:
    for element in Tag_1.iter():
    if element.getparent() is not None:
        print("parent-path:", element.getroottree().getpath(element.getparent()))
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting, Want to get Parent Attribute Values like Key/Code for each node in XML

Comment: Something like `('Key', '27880159'), ('Name', 'Nom')`?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting, Yes, I need like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code helped me:

```
XML_List = []
XML_Structure_All = pd.DataFrame()
for Tag_1 in XRoot[1]:
    for Child in Tag_1.iter():
    if len(Child.getparent().attrib) > 0:
        if 'CODE' in Child.getparent().attrib.keys():
        Parent = Child.getparent().attrib['CODE']
        elif 'C_CODE' in Child.getparent().attrib.keys():
        Parent = Child.getparent().attrib['C_CODE']
        elif 'KEY' in Child.getparent().attrib.keys():
        Parent = Child.getparent().attrib['KEY']
    else:
        Parent = ''

    if 'CODE' in Child.attrib.keys(): Col = 'CODE'
    elif 'C_CODE' in Child.attrib.keys(): Col = 'C_CODE'
    elif 'KEY' in Child.attrib.keys(): Col = 'KEY'

    XML_Dict = {'CODE': Child.attrib[Col], 'Parent': Parent}
    XML_List.append(XML_Dict)
XML_Dimension_Parent = pd.DataFrame(XML_List)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should get you several lists of tuples with key/value pairs:

```
for i in XRoot.xpath("//*['Key']"):
    print(i.items())
```

Example output:

```
[('Id', 'FULLNAME'), ('Key', '27880399'), ('Name', 'Nom complet')]
```

You can then add them to a dataframe, or whatever.